# Can anyone explain whats going on here? Two equal strings return false when compared

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

```
var numberA = "+6281237627470"; var numberB = "+6281237627470‬‬";

console.log(numberA == numberB);

==> false
```

Here is a link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0qrzq7x/20/)

Comment: Hint: `console.log(numberA.length, numberB.length);` Check the last character in B, that is after `0`

Comment: if you look at their length in that fiddle, A is 14 chars and B is 16. So there is something going on with your input. Not sure what though!

Comment: Invisible characters?

Comment: In the JSFiddle, they're equal if you append `String.fromCharCode(8236)` to the end of `numberA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are hidden characters that have ascii value 8236 at the end of numberB
You can verify them by

```
console.log(numberA.length, numberB.length) // 14, 16
console.log(numberA.split("").map(char => console.log(char.charCodeAt(0))))
console.log(numberB.split("").map(char => console.log(char.charCodeAt(0)))) // this will give two 8236 ascii value at the last of the string
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I actually ran them through a normalize function which was supposed to remove hidden chars as well - obviously not all of them^^:)